# REACT: Questions with tutorial code

Tags: reactjs

I am completely new to react and I have a question on the following tutorial code.

```
var Board = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var className = "board";
    if (this.props.selected) {
      className += " selected";
    }
    return (
      <div className={className}>
        {this.props.index + 1}
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var BoardSwitcher = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var boards = [];
    for (var ii = 0; ii < this.props.numBoards; ii++) {
      var isSelected = ii === 0;
      boards.push(
        <Board index={ii} selected={isSelected} key={ii} />
      );
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="boards">{boards}</div>
        <button>Toggle</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <BoardSwitcher numBoards={3} />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

According to the exercise, the first board is always selected (var isSelected = ii === 0). However, I don't see why it is this way. it will only be strictly equal to 0 during its first iteration. It makes isSelected equals to "true" for the first iteration and "false" for all the iterations, so it is not always selecting the first board.

The index of the board will be equals to ii and it will be updated by 1 whenever the render is called.

What is wrong with my thought process?

Comment: It is always marking the first board it creates as selected, and all the later ones to not selected.  The loop is creating 3 boards and setting the very first one to selected.  So every time you start this up it marks the very first board made as selected, and the others as not.

Comment: When is the board created  by boards.push?

Comment: The board index is set to equal ii, and also selected is equal to the Boolean that comes from ii === 0, which only happens for the first board.  There are 3 instances of Board.  The 3 Boards would be `[<Board index=0 selected=true />, <Board index=1 selected=false />, <Board index=2 selected=false />]`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are thinking more than you should on this one and you can see this loop happens in a syncronous way therefore the first square of the board will be added to the array with the board and seleacted class added. the other ones will not because the statement wont evaluate to true only on the first case.